# Div moves down to the bottom of the page and not button of screen height in iOS

Tags: ios, css, position, height

On my website I've a menu-button but the problem is that when the site is viewed in iPhone and iPad the button ends up at the bottom of the page and not at the bottom of the screen. So you can't see the button until you scroll down to the bottom of the page.

I read that there are some issues with iOS so I guess it got something to do with that. That the `bottom: 0;` moves the button to the page bottom and not screen bottom. But this only happens after you pressed the button (and the menu toggles out from the left)

What I want is simply that the button should stay at the button of the screen no matter what. And I guess it doesn't in this case because of the menu, because of the fact that it works before clicking on it.

My CSS:

```css
.nav-box {  /* this is the button */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #b26f7e;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 4px 13px 4px 12px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fafafa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pushmenu { /*this is the nav*/
    background: #72ce9b;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetics, sans-serif;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 998;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left text-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/sv/">
        <img src="" width="200" style="margin-top: 20px;" />
    </a>
    <ul class="text-left">

<li></li>



    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="nav-box">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about the button `.nav-box` showing up out of sight at the bottom of the page? If so most of the rest of the question is probably a distraction.

The first thing that I see is that `.nav-box` has `top: 0` instead of `bottom:0`. Did you mean for it to be at the top or the bottom?

Comment: I move it down on mobile, will change that

Comment: And yes, that's my problem. But I think it has something to do with the menu because it works till you press the nav-box, which opens the menu and that's why I've that code here

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to focus only on the problem at hand as much as possible. Anything you can eliminate from the explanation and the code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem should be removed. Also, including the relevant HTML would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the question the best I can now. And I don't think the html is relevant in this case due to the fact that it is working as it should in all the other browsers and devices, the issue is that iOS have another way of dealing with viewheight or something. It's just for iPhone and iPad that I need a solution / workaround

Comment: I only mentioned the HTML because I'm trying to reconstruct the problem you're having, and I'm having to make guesses at what the HTML structure you're using is.

Comment: Question: is the bottom of `.pushmenu` actually at the bottom of the screen? Or is it, too, going below the screen?

Comment: I have updated my question with my HTML. The ´.pushmenu´ gets as heigh as the page (as in below the screen), which I guess is why the button ends up at the end too.